# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/glassfish/jersey/server/spi/Container

Tags: maven, jetty, jersey-2.0

I am trying to set up a Jersey 2 servlet application. The goal is to map only some URLs to a Jersey REST API while other URLs serve static content.

I use `mvn compile war:war` to generate a war and deploy it. When deploying the artifact the following error occurs:

```
[2016-01-09 02:50:21,617] Artifact Test.war: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
2016-01-09 14:50:25.823:WARN:oejd.DeploymentManager:Scanner-1: Unable to reach node goal: started
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/glassfish/jersey/server/spi/Container
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.findClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:549)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:475)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:428)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.BaseHolder.doStart(BaseHolder.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:347)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:892)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:346)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1380)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1342)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:772)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:259)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:518)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.WebAppProvider.fileAdded(WebAppProvider.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:529)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:392)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner$1.run(Scanner.java:329)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
Caused by: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.Container
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:487)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:428)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.findClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:549)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:475)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:428)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.BaseHolder.doStart(BaseHolder.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:347)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:892)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:346)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1380)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1342)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:772)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:259)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:518)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.WebAppProvider.fileAdded(WebAppProvider.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:529)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:392)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner$1.run(Scanner.java:329)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
[2016-01-09 02:50:26,121] Artifact Test.war: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
```

my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>group.id</groupId>
    <artifactId>ProjectName</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-jetty-http</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-jetty-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>Test</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webXml>web/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ApiApplication</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>org.glassfish.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>group.id</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ApiApplication</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

The Jersey 2 application configuration ApiApplication.java:

```
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;

@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class ApiApplication extends ResourceConfig {
    public ApiApplication() {
        packages(true, "group.id");
    }
}
```

The test resource Test.java:

```
package group.id;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;

@Path("/test")
public class Test {
    @GET
    public String get() {
        return "Hello world!";
    }
}
```

When I look into the WAR-file the WEB-INF/lib is filled with JAR-files. Why can't Jetty deploy the WAR-file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These three dependencies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

are already pulled in by this dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-jetty-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.1</version>
</dependency>
```

But when you declare them, you override the fact that it pulls them in. And you are declaring them as `provided`

```
<scope>provided</scope>
```

which means that you are saying the server has those dependencies, which it doesn't. If you look in the WEB-INF/lib, you will see that those three are not there. That's the reason for the error. The best thing to do is just get rid of those three, since they are already pulled in.

You can actually get rid of *everything* except that last one, as it pulls in everything you declared.